# Redirect based on device width and height in MVC and jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I need to redirect an MVC application from www.company.com to www.company.com/mobile when the device accessing the website as the width under 640px and height under 960px.

I would prefer to detect in the server where occurs the first contact of the request so I don't need to load the layout and detect at the client side (if I'm not wrong).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this: [Switchable Desktop/Mobile Site with jQuery and MVC]http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks! yes I saw it but he don't talk about width detection or redirect that it's what I need. The mobile version is static and not integrated with the MVC application for future phonegap integration purpose.

Answer (score 1):

After studding different ways to get the width and height, I have decided to use this one:

```
    <script>
        var width = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

        if (width < 960 || height < 620)
        {
            // screen is too small, redirect to mobile version
            location.href = '/Mobile/index.html';
        }

    </script>
```

The other option was:

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Redirect mobile users to the mobile home page
        int wight = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth;
        int height = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight;

        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            string path = httpRequest.Url.PathAndQuery;
            bool isOnMobilePage = path.StartsWith("/Mobile/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (!isOnMobilePage)
            {

                if (wight < 720 && height < 1280) 
                { 
                    string redirectTo = "~/Mobile/Index.html";

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectTo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it's unbale to get the width and height of the device.